# Navigate to a particular database in SSMS

Tags: ssms

Is there a way to directly open objects in a particular database without loading the whole list of databases on a SQL server?

I tried putting in `Database=[name]` and `Initial Catalog=[name]` in the Additional Connection Parameters, but that didn't work.

I also tried setting the `[name]` in `Connect to database` parameter on the Connection Properties tab, and that did not work either.

Any way to do it?

Comment: On any `New Query` window, you can type `use [databasename]` before the SQL that you are executing.

Comment: I want to directly navigate to a particular database on the Object Explorer after I connect to a server.

Comment: Unfortunately ObjectExplorer loads all databases from the server before you can navigate to particular one.